# Why is this program returning the last word and not the longest word?

Tags: c++

Why is this program returning garbage values? I expect the output to be the word 'large', but the value is actually 'rat' - the last word.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

std::string LongestWord(std::string sen)
{

    std::string s2, lW;
    for (int i = 0; i < sen.size(); ++i) {

        while (sen[i] != ' ') {
            s2 += sen[i];
            ++i;
        }
        if (s2.size() > lW.size()) {
            lW = ""; lW = s2;
        }

        s2 = "";
    }
    return lW;
}
int main(void)
{

    cout << LongestWord("a cat ate the large rat") << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please indent the code before posting your question.

Comment: it's indented by 4 spaces

Comment: I updated the title as the values [shown] aren't "garbage" so the update is at least marginally better given the provided example and content of the question. Work to align the two.

Comment: When you test the last word, "rat" in this case, there isn't a blank after it, there is a null.  You then copy perhaps thousands of characters into s2 until you just happen to run into a space.  Its size is very large, but when you go print it the null stops cout.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. That makes sense.

Comment: @user2864740 Actually, when I ran OP's code in MSVC, the output was "rat" followed by a whole load of random (= 'garbage') characters.

Comment: @AdrianMole Which is entirely acceptable, as would be dinosaurs flying (aside: Axe Cop!), or the program failing without any output. However, such was not as reported by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your internal `while` loop will almost certainly run beyond the end of the given `string` argument (unless it has a space at the end). Change this internal loop to check for the size of that string, as follows:

```cpp
        while (i < sen.size() && sen[i] != ' ') {
            s2 += sen[i];
            ++i;
        }
```